# in Objective C, is it possible to use a selector from outside of the class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, selector

For example I have a method that looks like this

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(someMethod) 
                       withObject:data
                    waitUntilDone:YES];
```

In which "someMethod" is from another class. If it is possible, how can I do that?
Also, I'd like to know how can I pass in the parameters.

Assume that someMethod is defined as:

```
- (void)someMethod:(NSData *)data otherArg:(NSString *)arg;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can call selector of another class as well.

If selector is class method -

```
[ClassName performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(someMethod:) 
                   withObject:data
                waitUntilDone:YES];
```

and method signature is something like -

```
+ (void)someMethod:(returntype)somearg
```

If selector is instance method -

```
[classInstance performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(someMethod:) 
                   withObject:data
                waitUntilDone:YES];
```

and method signature is something like -

```
- (void)someMethod:(returntype)somearg
```

Comment: So, why not calling [ClassName someMethod:data] or [classInstance someMethod:data] directly? Any differences?

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace `self` with an instance of the class that defines the method.  Otherwise you will get an unrecognized selector error.  Also, don't forget to put a colon ( `:` ) after `someMethod` if you are sending it an argument.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If 'self' inherits from the class that implements `someMethod`, then you can of course do that. But you can't send a message to an object whose class (or ancestor class) doesn't implement that method. (Well, you can, but expect an error.)

The code snippet you show is similar to:

```
[self someMethod:data];
```

except that `someMethod:` will run on the main thread rather than whatever thread is currently executing. Looking at it that way may help you remember that the receiver (`self` in this case, but it could be a pointer to any object) has to implement the message you're sending.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of self, you replace that with the instance of the class you want to perform the selector on.

Comment: Not the class.  You mean an instance of the class.

Comment: An **instance** of the class you want to perform the selector on. `[self` implies that he's attempting to call an instance method, not a class method. (edit: @aroth got to it before me :)

Answer (score 0):

The message you want to send takes two parameters, and there's no variant of `performSelectorOnMainThread:...` that passes two parameters with the message.

The easiest way to do this is to use Grand Central Dispatch and a block.  If you are **sure** that you will not do this **on** the main thread, you can do this:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [otherObject someMethod:myData otherArg:@"my argument"];
});
```

But if you run that code when you're already on the main thread, that code will deadlock - your app will hang.

If you might want to do it when you're **already** on the main thread, you have to be more careful to avoid deadlock.  I'd do it like this:

```
dispatch_block_t block = ^{
    [otherObject someMethod:myData otherArg:@"my argument"];
};

if (dispatch_get_current_queue() == dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    block();
} else {
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
}
```